# FluentMigrator command returning No migration found

Tags: c#, .net, fluent-migrator

I created a new public class M203_InsertPercent that will just insert data into the database base on the SQL statement. When I run the Migrate.exe using the connection string and the assembly FluentMigrator.Console returns "No migration found". I look into the database in the version table and my class name is not in that table. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure your migration class is public as well :

https://github.com/fluentmigrator/documentation/blob/master/articles/faq.md

Answer (score 5):

Make sure your migration class is decorated with the `Migration` attribute.

```
[Migration(203)]
public class M203_InsertPercent : Migration
{
    ...
}
```